# Safety in Ukraine

Tags: safety, ukraine, lgbt

I am spending a week in Ukraine as part of an LGBT performing arts group.  We will be under the protection of the US Embassy and will be visiting Lviv and Kiev.  I know very little about the region, but I am aware that gay people are not necessarily treated with kindness there.  What should I be aware of while there?  Am I right to be apprehensive?

Comment: "under the protection of the US Embassy" Do you mean this is an officially sponsored US government visit, with embassy officials escorting you at all times?

Comment: Problem with your question is that it is very broad and invites opionions instead of objective answers. Could you please edit, e.g. instead of asking "is it safe" ask "what precautions should I take as an LGBT traveller" and be as specific about your activities as possible. Otherwise your question is likely to be closed which would be a pity.

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes.  I am told that there will be times to travel on our own, but I think it is more along the lines of "OK, here's an hour to go shopping in this town square" or whatnot.

Comment: The advice you get from US embassy officials or escorts is going to be much, much better than anything you are likely to get here. In fact I would recommend coming back here after your trip and posting your own answer to this question, based on their advice, so that others without the benefits of embassy escorts can read it.

Comment: You should read the [State Department's guidance on Ukraine](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/ukraine.html) and follow the instructions of the embassy staff who will be sure to brief you when you arrive.